# how to get a sim unique number programmatically to identify the sim uniquely

Tags: ios

I have an ios application connected with a web service. in server side my phone sim should be uniquely identifyed. In android version it can send a unique code to identify the sim. For iOS is there any possibility to get unique key for the sim. If so how can I do that?

Comment: What about non-cellular iOS devices? They don't have sim cards.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not allowed in any publicly available iOS API. You can only do this on a jail broken device.